# Disable openmsp430 interrupts by default

Tags: msp430

Are interrupts enabled by default in [OpenMSP430](https://opencores.org/projects/openmsp430/core), where is this defined in the [code](https://github.com/freecores/openmsp430/), apart from the watchdog enable/disable flag in `_defines.v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any msp430 I remeber gie is not enabled by default. The same seems to happen in OpenMSP430, see [omsp_register_file.v](https://github.com/freecores/openmsp430/blob/master/core/rtl/verilog/omsp_register_file.v)

```
    always @(posedge mclk_r2 or posedge puc_rst)
      if (puc_rst)         r2 <= 16'h0000;
```

Comment: What is the R2 status register?

Comment: Status register, it contains the gie flag (general interrupt enable) ALU flags, powersaving triggers and other things, don't remember seriusly.